# Cache SSL files with readFileSync in node, not read them every time

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, file-read

I am trying to set up SSL in my node and I am following this [guide](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) here. Now, according to the note,

"fs.readFileSync will block the entire process until it completes"

How can I have the key and cert files read only once, cache them somehow and then read them automatically from cache, so the whole process becomes faster?

Also, is there a way, or any point at making this non-blocking?

Thanks

Comment: In this case it is okay to use fs.readFileSync, because it is starting the server --that usually happens only once (and when restart is required).

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon Ok, but what about the cache? So the whole process is faster. Thanks again

Comment: As you agree with above comment, I would suggest you to read following links, it will help you decide what you actually need and how can you achieve that:
link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/
link: https://bambielli.com/til/2017-04-30-node-require-cache/
link: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Answer (score 1):

> How can I have the key and cert files read only once?

Use the fact that `requires` caches modules, and use an intermediary modules to expose your keys. Something in the likes of:

```
// keys.js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

exports.key = fs.readFileSync('key.pem');
exports.cert = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem');
```

```
// elsewhere
const { key, cert } = require('path/to/keys.js');
```

Note that this is only useful to replace many reads of ssl files by one file read. In the case you mention, ssl files are read once, so there is not really any need for caching.

> Is there a way, or any point at making this non-blocking?

Yes, use `readFile` instead of `readFileSync`. Then again, will not provide substantial performance gain in your particular case, but you can refactor the guide's server file like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

// use promises rather than callbacks, for a simpler code
const { promisify } = require('utils');
const readFilePromise = promisify(fs.readFile);

// wrap everything in an IIFE
(async () => {

  // read both files at once, in a non-blocking way
  const [ key, cert ] = await Promise.all([
    readFilePromise('key.pem'),
    readFilePromise('cert.pem'),
  ]);

  // create https server as usual
  https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);

})();
```

Comment: How does this answers the OP?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon because he asks two questions and I answer both of them

Comment: alright :) - I thought it differently and made it clear that it is okay to do it the way it is said in tutorial, also for cache provide links to learn.